# AST tree in antlr

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3, dot

i am trying to write parser for DOT(graphviz) language using antlr.
there is a problem when antlr generates parse tree .some times when i debug my grammer with some input and trace the steps of tree generation ,  i can see that some subtrees are exactly duplicated in my tree. at first time it comes with green color but exactly after that the same subtree will come with black color.
on a quick look it seems that it happens when i use "?" (operator) in my grammer
as you know this operator means some token is opational.

does anyone have any idea why even antlr trying to change the color of tree?!

here is my grammer :

```
grammar Dot;

options {
    backtrack = true; 
    memoize = true;
    output = AST;
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

tokens {
    // operators and special characters
    O_BRACKET = '{';
    C_BRACKET = '}';
    O_SQR_BRACKET = '[';
    C_SQR_BRACKET = ']';
    SEMI_COLON = ';';
    EQUAL = '=';
    COMMA = ',';
    COLON = ':';
    LPAREN = '(';
    RPAREN = ')';

    // case-insensitive keywords
    GRAPH;
    DIGRAPH;
    STRICT;
    NODE;
    EDGE;
    SUBGRAPH;

    // tokens from imaginary nodes
    GRAPH_ROOT;
    SUBGRAPH_ROOT;
    STMT_LIST;
    EDGE_STMT;
    NODE_STMT;
    ATTR_LIST;
    ATTR;
}

@header {
package org.cesta.parsers.dot;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
}

@members {
    private boolean hasErrors = false;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    public void setLogger(Logger newLogger){
        logger = newLogger;
    }

    @Override
    public void emitErrorMessage(String message) {
        hasErrors = true;
    if (logger!=null) logger.warning(message);
        super.emitErrorMessage(message);
    }

    public boolean hasErrors(){
        return hasErrors;
    }
}

@lexer::header {
package org.cesta.parsers.dot;
}

@lexer::members {
}

graph
    :   
        graphModifier ID? O_BRACKET stmt_list C_BRACKET 
        -> ^(GRAPH_ROOT graphModifier ID? stmt_list)
    ;

graphModifier
        :   
            (STRICT)? (GRAPH | DIGRAPH)
        ;

stmt_list
    :  stmt (SEMI_COLON* stmt)* SEMI_COLON* -> ^(STMT_LIST stmt+)
    ;

stmt
    :  
        attr_stmt |
        edge_stmt  |
        subgraph |
        ID EQUAL ID  -> ^(ATTR ID EQUAL ID) |
         node_stmt 
    ;

attr_stmt
    :  (GRAPH^ | NODE^ | EDGE^) (attr_list)
    ;

attr_list
    :   
        (O_SQR_BRACKET a_list? C_SQR_BRACKET)*
        -> ^(ATTR_LIST a_list*)
    ;

a_list
    :  (attr COMMA!?)+ 
    ;

attr
    :
        ID (EQUAL ID)? -> ^(ATTR ID (EQUAL ID)?)
    ;

edge_stmt
    :  
         node_subgraph edgeRHS attr_list?
        -> ^(EDGE_STMT node_subgraph edgeRHS attr_list?)
    ;

node_subgraph
    :   
    (node_id | subgraph)
    ;

edgeRHS
    :  EDGEOP^ (node_id | subgraph) (edgeRHS)?
    ;

node_stmt
    :  node_id (attr_list)? -> ^(NODE_STMT node_id attr_list?)
    ;

node_id    
    :  ID^ (port)?
    ;

port
    : 
        COLON! ID (COLON! VALIDSTR)? |
        COLON! VALIDSTR
    ;

subgraph
    :  
        O_BRACKET stmt_list? C_BRACKET 
            -> ^(SUBGRAPH_ROOT stmt_list?)

        |(SUBGRAPH O_BRACKET) => 
            SUBGRAPH ID? O_BRACKET stmt_list? C_BRACKET 
            -> ^(SUBGRAPH_ROOT ID? stmt_list?) 

        | SUBGRAPH ID? O_BRACKET stmt_list? C_BRACKET 
            -> ^(SUBGRAPH_ROOT ID? stmt_list?) 
        |
        SUBGRAPH ID 
            -> ^(SUBGRAPH_ROOT ID)
    ;

// LEXER

// case-insensitive keywords
GRAPH: G R A P H;
DIGRAPH: D I G R A P H;
STRICT: S T R I C T;
NODE: N O D E;
EDGE: E D G E;
SUBGRAPH: S U B G R A P H;

EDGEOP : '->' | '--';

ID
    :  (  VALIDSTR
        | NUMBER
        | QUOTEDSTR
        | HTMLSTR
       );



fragment ALPHACHAR 
    :  (   'a'..'z'
        |  'A'..'Z'
        |  '_'
       );


fragment VALIDSTR
    :  ALPHACHAR
        (  ALPHACHAR
         |  '0'..'9'
        )*
    ;

fragment NUMBER
    :  ('-')? ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
    ;

fragment QUOTEDSTR
    :  '"'
        STR
       '"'
    ;

fragment STR
    :
        (ESCAPE_SEQUENCE | ~('\\'|'"') )*
    ;

fragment ESCAPE_SEQUENCE
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    ;

fragment HTMLSTR
    :  '<' (~'>')* '>'
    ;

WS  :  (' '|'\t')+
    {
        $channel = HIDDEN;
    }
    ;

NEWLINE  :  ('\r' '\n'|'\r'|'\n'|'\u000C')
    {
        $channel = HIDDEN;
    }
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/'
    {
        $channel = HIDDEN;
    }
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    : '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n'
    {
        $channel = HIDDEN;
    }
    ;

fragment A:('a'|'A');
fragment B:('b'|'B');
fragment C:('c'|'C');
fragment D:('d'|'D');
fragment E:('e'|'E');
fragment F:('f'|'F');
fragment G:('g'|'G');
fragment H:('h'|'H');
fragment I:('i'|'I');
fragment J:('j'|'J');
fragment K:('k'|'K');
fragment L:('l'|'L');
fragment M:('m'|'M');
fragment N:('n'|'N');
fragment O:('o'|'O');
fragment P:('p'|'P');
fragment Q:('q'|'Q');
fragment R:('r'|'R');
fragment S:('s'|'S');
fragment T:('t'|'T');
fragment U:('u'|'U');
fragment V:('v'|'V');
fragment W:('w'|'W');
fragment X:('x'|'X');
fragment Y:('y'|'Y');
fragment Z:('z'|'Z');
```